# Keeping UIStatusBar out of the layout before iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, ios6, uistatusbar

In my iOS application, `Status Bar` is normally `hidden` (on start of the application too).

In some parts of the application I make it `visible`.

On `iOS6` and `iOS7` layout works perfectly and `Status Bar` overlaps any views on both iOS versions (I already want it to overlap, so it is OK).

However, I noticed that while on `iOS6` and while the status bar is visible, if I rotate the device (my application supports every orientation), the layout is shifted down because of the `Status Bar` and I can not fix it after that point.

What am I doing wrong? How can I make it overlap the views on rotation change too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was obvious though it can be forgotten. (like in my situation)

`self.wantsFullScreenLayout=YES;`

Comment: This function is deprecated